# How to make a square out of a rectangular face?

Tags: vertices, transforms, scale

I want this face to be a perfect square, I know about the addon looptools and Circle does make it square but also rotate the face which I don't wont. I know I could set my 3D cursor in the center of this face, add a plane, vertex snapping etc but is there an easier, faster method?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the size of the square you do want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use **Set Length** operator from **Mesh Tools** add-on.

[image]

Transcript of the GIF:

Select one edge, press <kbd>N</kbd> to enable *Numbers* panel, go to *Edit* tab > *Mesh Tools* > *Edge Tools* > **Set Edge Length**. Hover your mouse over *Target Length* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the current length.

Select Two edges connected to the measured one, again click on *Set Edge Length*, hover over *Target Length*, but this time paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
and accept by clicking the **OK** button (out of frame here).

Comment: Wow, Exact and fast! Great! Looks like the easiest way ;)

Comment: You're telling me it's enough to *hover over* the field I want to copy? The click-click-clicks I could've saved :D

Answer (score 6):

When you ask for a **perfect** square, you're asking to manipulate individual vertices to place them exactly, and the ways I know how to do this are tedious.  The easiest way to get a reasonable square is to

Inset the face so that one pair of opposite sides are the right length for the square.  For my example, I'm going to pick the pair that are parallel to the Y axis:

[image: Inset face, with Y sides approximately correct.]

Switch to edge select and select the pair of edges that are the correct length:

[image: selecting the correct length sides]

Scale along the perpendicular axis, in my example, the X axis, until you have an approximate square:

[image: Approximately square sides]

If you turn on edge length in the overlays then you can see the value of the lengths of the square and improve your approximation:

[image: turning on edge length]

[image: edge lengths]

If you need even more precision, you can do numerical input when you do the inset.  In this example, I entered 'i.25' to make the border .25 units, resulting in the y length being .5.

[image: more control]

Now I can do a little arithmetic and learn what scale factor I need to bring the other two sides to the correct length.  Since .5 is 1/3 of 1.5, the length of the long side of the rectangle, I typed 'sx.333' to obtain this result:

[image: exact square.]

Unfortunately, as far as I know, Blender doesn't offer an option for inset to make the sides square, so manipulation similar to this is required.

Of course, if your face isn't parallel to one of the axis, then you need to adjust the technique.  Often, working in normal space rather than global space works, and when all else fails you can create a custom space.

Comment: +1 from me, your screenshots make the answer seem longer and harder than it really is :)